# Swiper.js Carousel How to control multiple carousel with middle mouse at the same time

Tags: javascript, css, carousel, swiper.js

I have 5 carousel on the screen they all are controlled by same navigation buttons.I also need to control them with middle mouse scroll. When i activate mouse wheel control only the carousel which mouse is on top is moving when scrolled. I need to move them all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a better solution but i did it this way.

```
// Wheel Control on Carousels

$( '#body' ).on( 'mousewheel', function ( event ) {
  if ( typeof event.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY === 'undefined' ) {
  console.log( "could not find mouse deltas" )
}
var deltaY = event.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY;
var scrolledUp = deltaY < 0;
var scrolledDown = deltaY > 0;
if ( scrolledUp ) {
  if (swiper_color.activeIndex > 2) {
goTop();
  }else{
  swiper_color.slidePrev();
  swiper_image.slidePrev();
  swiper_desc.slidePrev();
  swiper_title.slidePrev();
  swiper_jar.slidePrev();
  }
  }
  if ( scrolledDown ) {
if (swiper_color.activeIndex < 2) {
  swiper_color.slideNext();
  swiper_image.slideNext();
  swiper_desc.slideNext();
  swiper_title.slideNext();
  swiper_jar.slideNext();
}else{
  checkscroll();
}
   }
});
```